# Finding difference between date-times in same column separated by some number of rows

Tags: r, diff, data.table

I'm currently examining a number of subjects (*id*) and how many times they are recorded visiting a specific location (*location*) over a course of time. Rather than visually-identifying when each subject has arrived at a location and recording the date-time (*datetime*), we are utilizing simple motion detection as to increase our coverage. Unfortunately, some of these technologies can record "false detections" which would make it appear as if a subject was present when it truly was not.

In order to confidently assume that a subject did visit the location, the manufacturer recommends that there must be at least **3 recordings per 30 minutes**. The `df` data.table/data.frame below is an example:

```
> df <- data.table(df, key = c("id", "location", "datetime"))
> df
    id            datetime location
 1:  1 2014-06-01 08:03:00        a
 2:  1 2014-06-01 08:56:00        a
 3:  1 2014-06-01 08:58:00        a
 4:  1 2014-06-01 09:09:00        a
 5:  1 2014-06-01 09:20:00        a
 6:  1 2014-06-01 08:28:00        b
 7:  1 2014-06-01 08:33:00        b
 8:  1 2014-06-01 08:38:00        b
 9:  1 2014-06-01 08:42:00        b
10:  1 2014-06-01 09:31:00        b
11:  1 2014-06-01 08:18:00        c
12:  1 2014-06-01 08:50:00        c
13:  1 2014-06-01 08:52:00        c
14:  1 2014-06-01 08:53:00        c
15:  1 2014-06-01 09:05:00        c
16:  2 2014-06-01 09:35:00        a
17:  2 2014-06-01 09:45:00        a
18:  2 2014-06-01 10:40:00        a
19:  2 2014-06-01 10:44:00        a
20:  2 2014-06-01 10:59:00        a
21:  2 2014-06-01 11:04:00        a
22:  2 2014-06-01 09:54:00        b
23:  2 2014-06-01 10:12:00        b
24:  2 2014-06-01 09:40:00        c
25:  2 2014-06-01 10:01:00        c
26:  2 2014-06-01 10:07:00        c
27:  2 2014-06-01 10:19:00        c
28:  2 2014-06-01 10:32:00        c
29:  2 2014-06-01 10:49:00        c
30:  2 2014-06-01 10:57:00        c
```

The key used above organizes the data by subject (*id*), their visited locations (*location*) and the time they visited the locations (*datetime*). By organizing the data.table in this way, all that needs to be done is determine if and when the time between 3 consecutive recordings exceeds 30 minutes. My desired output would be the following:

```
> df
    id            datetime location diff_min
 1:  1 2014-06-01 08:03:00        a       55
 2:  1 2014-06-01 08:56:00        a       13
 3:  1 2014-06-01 08:58:00        a       22
 4:  1 2014-06-01 09:09:00        a       NA  <-----
 5:  1 2014-06-01 09:20:00        a       NA  <-----
 6:  1 2014-06-01 08:28:00        b       10
 7:  1 2014-06-01 08:33:00        b        9
 8:  1 2014-06-01 08:38:00        b       53
 9:  1 2014-06-01 08:42:00        b       NA  <-----
10:  1 2014-06-01 09:31:00        b       NA  <-----
11:  1 2014-06-01 08:18:00        c       34
12:  1 2014-06-01 08:50:00        c        3
13:  1 2014-06-01 08:52:00        c       13
14:  1 2014-06-01 08:53:00        c       NA  <-----
15:  1 2014-06-01 09:05:00        c       NA  <-----
16:  2 2014-06-01 09:35:00        a       65
17:  2 2014-06-01 09:45:00        a       59
18:  2 2014-06-01 10:40:00        a       19
19:  2 2014-06-01 10:44:00        a       20
20:  2 2014-06-01 10:59:00        a       NA  <-----
21:  2 2014-06-01 11:04:00        a       NA  <-----
22:  2 2014-06-01 09:54:00        b       NA  <-----
23:  2 2014-06-01 10:12:00        b       NA  <-----
24:  2 2014-06-01 09:40:00        c       27
25:  2 2014-06-01 10:01:00        c       18
26:  2 2014-06-01 10:07:00        c       25
27:  2 2014-06-01 10:19:00        c       30
28:  2 2014-06-01 10:32:00        c       25
29:  2 2014-06-01 10:49:00        c       NA  <-----
30:  2 2014-06-01 10:57:00        c       NA  <-----
```

Please take notice of the `<-----` that point out `NA` values. Since I am finding the `difftime()` two rows down from the initial value (3 recordings total), the last two rows/recordings per *id* and *location* would be `NA` because there are less than 3 recordings left. Any location with 2 or less recordings would automatically get `NA` values.

I attempted to solve this on my own with the following code but I am no closer to solving it:

```
> df[, diff_min := lapply(.SD, function(x) c(difftime(x[3:length(x)], x[1:(length(x)-2)], units = "mins"), NA, NA)), 
+    .SDcols = "datetime", by = c("id", "location")]
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(diff_min, lapply(.SD, function(x) c(difftime(x[3:length(x)],  :
  RHS 1 is length 4 (greater than the size (2) of group 5). The last 2 element(s) will be discarded.
```

Please see the following `dput()` output below if you care to try it out:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), datetime = structure(c(1401624180L, 
1401627360L, 1401627480L, 1401628140L, 1401628800L, 1401625680L, 
1401625980L, 1401626280L, 1401626520L, 1401629460L, 1401625080L, 
1401627000L, 1401627120L, 1401627180L, 1401627900L, 1401629700L, 
1401630300L, 1401633600L, 1401633840L, 1401634740L, 1401635040L, 
1401630840L, 1401631920L, 1401630000L, 1401631260L, 1401631620L, 
1401632340L, 1401633120L, 1401634140L, 1401634620L), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "datetime", "location"
), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), sorted = c("id", "location", "datetime"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000100788>)
```

Please feel free to ask questions and use any coding package to achieve the desired output (e.g. `base`, `dplyr`). Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rollapply` from zoo:

```
library(zoo)

Diff <- function(x) difftime(x[3], x[1], units = "min")
df[, diff_min := rollapply(datetime, 3, Diff, align = "left", fill = NA), 
       by = list(id, location)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have never used the `zoo` package but am glad to know it can handle such a task alongside `data.table`.